# .save() not saving in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
middleware.addSingleFileToAWS(req, function(upload) { //this works
    console.log(upload.error); //errors in the upload callback are displayed
    if (upload.error) {
        //send error message
        res.redirect("back");
    }
    else {
        updatedResponse.fileName = upload.params.s3Params.Key;
        updatedResponse.file = upload;
        updatedResponse.author.id = req.user; //security measures
        updatedResponse.author.username = req.user.username;
        console.log(updatedResponse); //updatedResponse prints correctly
        updatedResponse.save(); //the .save() method is not saving to the db
        foundApplication.response = updatedResponse;
        foundApplication.save(); //this works though
        res.redirect("/" + foundApplication._id + "/manage"); //res works
    }
 });
```

This is part of a Model.findByIdAndUpdate() method. The model is being updated with the information in the request form, but the save() method is not being called. otherwise, the rest of the code works find. I've done other code blocks written exactly like this one that work, but for some reason, it isn't saving here.

I've noticed that if I omit the updatedResponse.fileName = upload.params.s3Params.Key; and updatedResponse.file = upload; parts, the save() method works. Does mongoose give up or something?

All answers are appreciated thank you in advance

Comment: Where you declare  updatedResponse? Is it mongoose object?

Comment: you should check first `upload.params.s3Params.Key` and what is `upload` that you assigned in `file` those are valid or not

Comment: Yes. I found the problem to be when updatedResponse.file = upload; is declared. The upload object returned by the callback function is not a mongo object, but when save() is called, updatedResponse.file is supposed to be a mongoose object (as declared in the response schema). So save() can't be called. Super annoying error! Glad it works now!